# Dynamically position the content according to the content of top element

Tags: html, css, angular, sass, ionic4

Content of `<p>` tag loads dynamically and it has different height. I have used `ion-button` position as fixed `top` and etc. e.g. `margin-top: -20px;`. But this will not work on `p` has big data. So can you tell me how to handle this? i.e. I need to dynamically adjust the `ion-button` position.

*.html*

```
<ion-row>
  <ion-col size="12">
    <h3 class="title">{{ data?.name }}</h3>
    <p class="opening" [innerHTML]="data?.workingHours"></p>
    <ion-button *ngFor="let button of data.buttonlinks" fill="outline" 
      class="menu-button" color="primary">
      {{ button.name }}</ion-button>
    <div class="inner-html" [innerHTML]="data.description"></div>
  </ion-col>
</ion-row>
```

.scss

```
.opening {
    font-size: 14px;
    font-weight: 500;
    color: #4A4A4A;
}

.menu-button {
    margin-top: -20px;
    margin-bottom: 16px;
    margin-left: 16px;
}
```

UI:

[image]

Comment: Yes, but UI designer asks to do like I have done above. Can't I achieve the way I have tried? @Paulie_D

Comment: position: absolute; top: y, right: x;  on the button

Answer (score 2):

```
.menu-button {
    position: absolute; 
    top: 20px;
    right:20px;
}
```

Comment: I don't use Ion but it should work if the ion-col not is static. position: absolute; An element with position: absolute; is positioned relative to the nearest positioned ancestor (instead of positioned relative to the viewport, like fixed). However; if an absolute positioned element has no positioned ancestors, it uses the document body, and moves along with page scrolling.  the easiest is to make a stackblitz

Comment: check this (in standard css) : https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-dwzo6c?embed=1&file=src/app/app.component.css  (your parent container also need to be non-static (e.g. absolute to work)